# PHP cURL JSON Decode (X-AUTH Header)

Tags: php, curl, json

```
<?php

// Show Profile
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example/api");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-AUTH: 123456789'));
$projects = curl_exec($curl);

// This is empty?
echo $projects;

//Decode
$phpArray = json_decode($projects);
print_r($phpArray);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { // Line 17, sure its empty, but why?
echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}

?>
```

**Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/api.php **on line 17**

The API needs this authentification:

```
$ curl -i -H "X-AUTH: 123456789" https://example/api
```

JSON File:

```
{"id":"123456","hostId":null,"Nickname":"thecyx","DisplayName":"thecyx","AppDisplayName":"thecyx","Score":"300","Account":"Full"}
```

The $project variable is empty. If I'm posting the API Url in the Broswer its working.

And, if possible, what's the correct way to get the JSON Data e.g. [Nickname],[Score]?

Comment: You can get status code first with `$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` right after `$projects = curl_exec($curl);`, and tell me the response code, so we can comment further. And we need to know content of `$projects`

Comment: The Status Code is "0". Content of $projects is the JSON File "quote". Need more?

Comment: 0 means you are getting timeout. In browser, https://example/api works right? I mean a popup opens and when you add username and pass, you will be able to see json result

Comment: You can see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929900/php-curl-json-decode-x-auth-header/23930712#23930712)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending custom headers ok but you are saying that, you will use basic authentication with `CURLAUTH_BASIC`. However, you did not provide any username and password for basic auth. Do not use that. Your code should be like below;

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example/api");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-AUTH: 123456789'));
$projects = curl_exec($curl);
```

If you will use basic auth, you need to provide username and password like;

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example/api");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-AUTH: 123456789'));
$projects = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: tried the first one (i don't need username:password). But nothing changes. Still empty page and http status "0". With browser directly, the API Link works (without popup, i think its a cookie). //edit: with username:PW nothing, also.

Comment: But you are sending https? that is true?

Comment: Yeah, all API Urls are https

Comment: Use this `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)` I have updated in my asnwer also

Comment: Thanks! Now: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /html/api.php on line 7 (Line 7 is RETURNTRANSFER)